# Como concatenar células de acordo com critérios de outras células? VBA

Tags: envio-de-email, group-concat

Gente, tenho uma macro para enviar e-mail, ela funciona bem, mas no atualmente ela envia um e-mail por vez, eu preciso que ela envie tudo de uma vez de acordo com os cargos.

Obs: no If, ele compara a minha planilha que contem a macro com a base de colaboradores (planilha em outra pasta de trabalho), em ceels(4,3) tem um filtro de cargos que funciona bem. Eu só preciso que ao invés de mandar 30 e-mails para 30 gerentes, ele leia a planilha inteira e concatene os e-mails dos 30 gerentes e faça apenas 1 e-mail só.

Sei que para isso terei que tirar a parte de construir o e-mail do for, mas n sei como fazer a parte dele concatenar os e-mails de acordo com os cargos.

Ah, tem cargos na coluna 12 e na 27, mas se me ajudarem com a 12, depois na 27 dá para arrumar.

**Sub Enviar_Email()
Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set wb = Workbooks("Colaboradores.xlsx")**  *'Arquivo com os colaboradores*

**Última_Linha = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count** *'Quantidade de linhas na planilha de colaboradores*

```
**For Linha = 2 To Última_Linha  

    If Planilha1.Cells(4, 3).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Linha, 12).Value Or _
    Planilha1.Cells(4, 3).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Linha, 27).Value Or _
    Planilha1.Cells(4, 3).Value = "Todos" Then
        Set Email = objeto_outlook.CreateItem(0)
                 
        Email.Display
                    
        Email.To = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Linha, 9).Value 
                            
        Email.Subject = Planilha1.Cells(5, 3).Value**
            
                       
        **Email.HTMLbody = "<center>""<html><body><img src=" & Planilha1.Cells(7, 3).Value & "></body></html>" & "<br><br>"**  *'adiciona a imagem*
    
            
           **E-mail.Send
    End If
Next
```

End Sub**

Answer (score 0):

Essa Sub cria um array com as informações dos emails.

Adicione uma Sub como essa porém com as informações que você tem.

Eu nomearia todas as tabelas para facilitar o uso do VBA.

```
Sub emails()

  Dim Earr(1 To 20) As String
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook

  For linha = 1 To 6

    If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(linha, 3) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 7) Then

      Earr(linha) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(linha, 2).Value
      
     MsgBox Earr(linha)
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: Tabela base para execução do script]

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).